# Запуск всех функций при открытии страницы в JS

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать, чтобы при открытии страницы запустились все указанные функции?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {
  funcOne();
  funcTwo();
  ...
  funcN();
};
```